# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

hello guys i hope you can help me.

i have searched the error and it happens for many people but it still didnt explain my case. i keep getting this error when i make compile my c++ source code.

```
Error   1   *error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int*
```

please help it's happening in all the code i create, even the small stuff. here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }

main()
{
    cout << "enter two small full values. each folowed by the enter key";
    int val1;
    int val2;
    cin >> val1;
    cin >> val2;
    if (val1 > val2)
        cout << "\nthe lagest number you typed was: \n" << val1;
    if (val2 > val1)
        cout << "the lagest number you typed was: \n" << val2;
    if (val1 > val2)
        cout << "the smaller number you typed was: \n" << val1;
    if (val2 > val1)
        cout << "the smaller number you typed was: \n" << val1;

    return 0;
}
```

thankyou in advance :D
K

Comment: Are you actually running this on a mainframe computer (MVS tag)? If so, it does not seem relevant with the code shown.

Comment: Just an annoying 'feature' of msvc - the compiler should stop right there and ignore all following errors (but it is happy playing with the int). See @Vlad from Moscow's answer, too.

Answer (score 3):

Function main shall have return type `int`

```
int main()
{
//...
}
```

From the C++ Standard (3.6.1 Main function)

> 2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It **shall have a return type of type
>   int**, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All
>   implementations shall allow both — a function of () returning int and
>   — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int as the
>   type of main (8.3.5).

Take into account that your program outputs nothing in case when two entered numbers are equal each other.

Also this statement

```
if (val1 > val2)
    cout << "the smaller number you typed was: \n" << val1;
```

is wrong. There should be

```
if (val1 > val2)
    cout << "the smaller number you typed was: \n" << val2;
```